# jquery before() after() are not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

actually i am trying to insert these(`<div class="error_msg_div"><div class="error_msgicon_div"><span class="sprite_16x16_group_errorinfo fl rmar5"></span></div><div class="error_msgtext_div">`) things before the ul 
and these(`</div><div class="error_msgcloseicon_div"><span class="sprite_16x16_group_blueclose_icon fl curpointer"></span></div><div class="clearfloat"></div></div>`) things after the ul.

But here it is inserting the div tags but it closing the divs automatically but i don't want that

because i am trying to push the ul to inside one div. that is not happening here
my **[jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/hrFuU/2/)**
Here is my script:

```
if($('span.error_span:has(ul.validation-messages)')){
                $('ul.validation-messages').before('<div class="error_msg_div"><div class="error_msgicon_div"><span class="sprite_16x16_group_errorinfo fl rmar5"></span></div><div class="error_msgtext_div">');
                $('ul.validation-messages').after('</div><div class="error_msgcloseicon_div"><span class="sprite_16x16_group_blueclose_icon fl curpointer"></span></div><div class="clearfloat"></div></div>');
            }​
```

Comment: you need to insert valid closing tags both before and after... look at the .wrap() method to wrap your content in content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be aware that you are manipulating the DOM with these functions, not just simply concatenating some strings containing HTML. You cannot append `</div>`.

You should use [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to add that div around your lists, and then use `before()` and `after()` to insert other divs.

```
$('ul.validation-messages')
    .wrap('<div class="error_msg_div">')
    .before('<div class="error_msgicon_div"><span class="sprite_16x16_group_errorinfo fl rmar5"></span></div><div class="error_msgtext_div">')
    .after('<div class="error_msgcloseicon_div"><span class="sprite_16x16_group_blueclose_icon fl curpointer"></span></div><div class="clearfloat"></div></div>');
```

Answer (score 3):

have you tried using [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) instead of `before` and `after`?